# How to validate Clarity Design Date Picker in Angular

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I have a rather simple question about Clarity Design System. I can't find any documentation for validating a date that the user manually enters into a `clrDate` control. Obviously the date picker would automatically take care of the date if selected from the calendar, but the docs don't mention which errors are emitted if the date is not valid.

**Edit**: I want to check whether the date text entered is valid, because the date control checks this internally, but I don't know how to validate it.

```html
    <clr-date-container>
        <label>Basic Demo</label>
        <input type="date" clrDate name="demo" [(ngModel)]="demo">
        <clr-error-control *clrIfError="'whatgoeshere'"></clr-error-control>
    </clr-date-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Datepicker is just a form control. Any of the usual Angular form validation strategy's will work.

### Template driven example

```
<form clrForm>
  <clr-date-container>
    <label>Basic Demo</label>
    <input type="date" clrDate name="demo" [(ngModel)]="demo" required>
  </clr-date-container>
</form>
```

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-62312324-datepicker-validation

## Update

Here is an updated Stackblitz that implements a custom validator for a template driven form: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-62312324-datepicker-validation-cbtfpf

Note, this is a quick poc and it will always fail as a demonstration for how custom validation works for a template driven clarity form control.

Note, most of this is just angular forms stuff. Clarity forms are set up to work on top of Angular forms and here, all you need to do is tell `*clrIfError` about the custom validator for what you want to check.

Comment: I’m not sure what is meant by valid. Can you create a minimal reproduction that clarifies the question? https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: As in whether the user correctly typed it in as a date that the clrDate component can actually parse. I can't figure out how to tell whether the date picker thinks it's valid.

Comment: You can use the validation built into Angular for template or reactive forms. Then set up `*clrIfError` for the validator (e.g pattern or customValidator). How to set up clr-control-error is described here: https://clarity.design/documentation/forms. Give it a shot and if you have trouble post your stackblitz here so I can see the running code you are working with.

Comment: Clarity has custom date processing. Is there any way to get the result of that custom code? I've dug into the clarity source code some and it isn't as simple as just using the built in validator I don't think. Not sure though.

Comment: If you show me what your are trying with a stackblitz I’m happy to look at the code.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use stack blitz, but I've added example code to my question. I am trying to figure out what goes in the `*clrIfError` attribute.

Comment: See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-62312324-datepicker-validation-ppxhox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: An error is not even given when an invalid date is entered.

Comment: I updated the answer with a second stackblitz. It shows how to implement a custom validator and tell `*clrIfError` about it.

Comment: Thank you, it appears though that clarity has no built-in mechanism for checking whether the date is valid. I will probably open a Github issue for this if I need it.

Comment: Clarity is just angular forms. If you need/want to validate the date control for incorrect formatting the Angular validates are the way to go. Also, ClrDate has to support both date obj and localized strings. You are welcome to file an issue - be clear about what’s different for your use case. It will help us decide if it’s something to consider. It’s been a while since I worked on the datepicker code but iir we have to support both date objects and the browser location format. the app relies on Angular forms to detect and show errors - not Clarity that might be why it’s not working for you.